# What is the addresses shown during backtrace in GDB pointing to?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm new to GDB. I'm wondering what exactly does the address 0xXXXX means at the beginning of each frame?

[image]

```
(gdb) bt
#0  g2 (a=4, b=34) at 2.7.c:10
#1  0x0000000008000703 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffffedd48) at 2.7.c:18
```

Is that the address of the Return Location or is that the address of where that the function begins?
Here's the applicable part of the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GomJJ.png)

```
int g2(int a, int b){
    int c = g1(a+3, b-11);
    printf("g2: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 17;
    int c = g2(a-1, b*2);
    printf("g3: a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of text, type out the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the return address within the function that will be returned to when the called code returns to this frame.  If you disassemble the code to main (`disas main`), you'll see the code of main with addresses, one of which will be the address in question (0x8000703), which will probably be the instruction immediately after a `call` instruction.